# Dynamic create Menu Bar in database and display in front end cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am working in a project in which i have to create MenuBar and pages from database. Which should be appear to front user. I have created MenuItem Model,Controller as well as View. My MenuItems also appearing in front end user. But now i want when i click on any menu item it's corresponding page's contents should appear. That thing making me very confuse how to link page with menu items. I am new to cakephp so please somebody explain me how to do this. Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Baking the cakephp code would automatically add vertical menu bar in your code and you can change accordingly

Comment: Really very thanks Ammu for your reply. I have done it, but now the problom is when i type the url "localhost/ProjectName" in address bar then the index page open which display the menu items(from menu_items table in database). But want to display some static page like about-us,contact-us etc. I have also created all pages in view->Pages, and also link these menu items with pages. But when i click on about-us or contact-us page it shows me an error "action display is not defined in controller PagesController"

Comment: In routes.php file.                                           'Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display')) Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'))'

Comment: Hey if you have to modify /app/views/pages/home.ctp for dispalying it a static page .You can make it as a home page for your application. Kindly up vote that comment if it helps you and feel free to ask further questions